# Increase the heap memory of jboss

Tags: java, jboss5.x, heap-memory

I am trying to increase the heap memory of my jboss server.

So I am changing in jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\run.conf file :

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048M"
```

but when I run jboss server it display me :

```
INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss 5.1 Runtime -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\lib\endorsed -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
```

So what is reason behind it?

I don't know actually memory is increase or not ?

Comment: Using SET is only valid for the current CMD session. Are you starting JBoss in the same session?

Comment: No I am starting through eclipse.

Comment: Just to note: the run.conf is used in the Linux startup shell script only. It won't have any effect on running JBoss on Windows. But when deploying from Eclipse, the scripts are not used at all and you need to configure it in the Eclipse server configuration itself.

Comment: @Gimby then what about windows.

Comment: Strange question to ask when you already accepted an answer. I also don't understand that you accept an answer that relates to starting from the shell when you are apparently starting JBoss through Eclipse.

Comment: I am just trying to know your view point. it may helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SET is only valid for the current CMD session which means the JAVA_OPTS variable you have defined will only be visible to JBoss if you start the server in the same CMD session.

As you are starting JBoss through eclipse, you will need to set the environment variable differently.

Not sure what version of Windows you have but in XP (old school), you can go to Control Panel->System and under Advanced, there should be an option to edit environment variables. Add your JAVA_OPTS variable here, restart eclipse and then launch JBoss again.

**[Edit]**

For Windows 7, see this link to help setting JAVA_OPTS variable: http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html

**variable name**: JAVA_OPTS
**variable value**: %JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048M

Comment: can you tell me that how can i set the environment variable ?

Comment: Which version of Windows do you have?

Comment: what is the variable name should i give ?

Comment: variable name: JAVA_OPTS

Comment: variable value: %JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048M

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"
```

Comment: We can set it as JVM arguments e.g. -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m for a minimum heap of 1GB and maximum heap of 2GB.

Comment: Yes, but OP is already doing this. The only difference you propose is to keep any old options and use less flags. Why do you think this would work better?